# Xcode and macOS - use different keychain for unit tests

Tags: xcode, keychain, provisioning-profile, sskeychain

I am trying to write some unit tests around the handling of keychain entry / retrieval, and would like to have the tests read/write from a different location while my app is running in the unit test bundle. Ideally it would be to setup a different keychain access group, but I know how to set it up so that the unit test provisioning profile has a different keychain access group than the target app. Is that possible? If not, what's the best way to accomplish this?